# Deleting a row from a table using sqlite3

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, sqlite

I am trying to delete a row from my code when the sell player is button is pressed but it doesn't happen and there are also no errors when it pressed.

I have tried making Self.Id a string as well as an int and it is an int in the original table. The class that its getting self from is just the class for the tkinter page.

Here is the relevant code does anybody know what I am doing wrong:

```
def get_sellernames(self):
    self.Seller_Firstname = self.E1.get()
    self.Seller_Lastname = self.E2.get()
    print(self.Seller_Firstname)
    print(self.Seller_Lastname)
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM yourplayers WHERE Firstname=? AND Secondname=?", (self.Seller_Firstname, self.Seller_Lastname))
    mylist = c.fetchall()
    self.Id = mylist[0][0]
    print(self.Id)
    self.B2 = Button(self, text="Sell player", command=lambda: self.Sell_player)
    self.B2.grid(row=20, column=5)
def Sell_player(self):
    self.Id = int(self.Id)
    c.execute("DELETE FROM yourplayers WHERE PlayerId=?", (self.Id,))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: It was just a simple error i forgot the brackets where the sell player function was being called i should tested that it was actually being run earlier (i forgot the brackets when calling it).